# How can I make Xampp secure for using as a local server?

Tags: xampp

I would like to develop PHP script in my PC. However, my PC also contain some importwnt information that I like to keep secure. Someone told me that installing xampp in my PC can make my PC insecure. I'm not sure how valid is this and if there are any setting that I should make after installing it to make my PC secure?

I search online about the issue of security when installing Xampp but I could not find clear information. Some say it is totally safe, others say it can open ways for hackers to log in to my PC.